# Encrypt/Decrypt Arabic String in C#

Tags: c#

How to Encrypt/Decrypt Arabic string in C# using these methods ????
Wheni try to decrypt any arabic string  its return "????" question marks.. How can use Encoding UTF8 through this code ??
Any help please .. 
thanks in advance

```
public static string Encrypt(string pDataToEncrypt)
{

    ASCIIEncoding textConverter = new ASCIIEncoding();
    RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
    byte[] toEncrypt;

    ICryptoTransform encryptor = myRijndael.CreateEncryptor(key, IV);

    MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor,            CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    toEncrypt = textConverter.GetBytes(pDataToEncrypt);

    csEncrypt.Write(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);
    csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();

    return Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)msEncrypt.Length);
}

public static string Decrypt(string pDataToDecrypt)
{
    RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
    byte[] fromEncrypt;

    //Encoding asciiEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;

    fromEncrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(pDataToDecrypt);
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = myRijndael.CreateDecryptor(key, IV);

    MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(fromEncrypt, 0, fromEncrypt.Length);
    CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csDecrypt);

    return sr.ReadToEnd();

}
```

Comment: are you using WPF, Windows Form or ASP.NET Web Forms?

Comment: how are you sending the string parameters to the functions? Are you reading a textbox?

Comment: yes using textbox ..

Comment: but now i using console application and there are the same problem

Comment: have you tried to save your webpage (the aspx file) with UTF8 encoding?

File >> Save As... >> Choose the Arrow on the Save Button >> Save with Encoding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using UTF-8 your code should be like this:

```
public static string Encrypt(string pDataToEncrypt)
{

    RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();

    ICryptoTransform encryptor = myRijndael.CreateEncryptor(key, IV);

    MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor,CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    byte[] toEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pDataToEncrypt);

    csEncrypt.Write(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);
    csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();

    return Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)msEncrypt.Length);
}

public static string Decrypt(string pDataToDecrypt)
{
    RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();

    byte[] fromEncrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(pDataToDecrypt);
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = myRijndael.CreateDecryptor(key, IV);

    MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(fromEncrypt, 0, fromEncrypt.Length);
    CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[fromEncrypt.Length];
    int decryptedByteCount = csDecrypt.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
}
```

Comment: Man i used your code !! Dose not work..

Comment: @karamalramahi it "dose not work" not enough info, I cannot help you further

Comment: I mean there are the same problem and I'm using console application

Comment: But you don't tell me what the problem is, this code I did not run it

Comment: Man I'm using console application and send the parameters to the functions through the void main .. When I try to encrypt Arabic string its return qustions mark "???"